# Is “steal” a good word for something like grabbing someone's weapon in the course of a struggle?

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes when there's news about a struggle of sort and someone tries to grab another's weapon to disarm or shoot them, some people would comment on it saying things like,

> the guy attacked the gun owner and tried to steal the guy's gun

or

> officials said he resisted arrest and stole an officer's Taser

I understand that the term is probably a technically correct one, but isn't “steal” more suitable for things you take, often without the victim's notice, to keep for yourself, or sell? There's just such a big disconnect between things like these and grabbing a gun to save your life. It feels like the only reason to use the word “steal” here would be to paint the “thief” in a bad light. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You are probably right.

Comment: As this is English Language and Usage, and as you realise that language can be used emotively, it is unlikely that you will receive more than an opinion. The author of the piece thought that "steal" was entirely appropriate and that is the end of the matter. :)

Comment: Connotations of words are hardly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[steal](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/steal)

> v. t. 1.  To take, and carry away, feloniously; to take without right or leave, and with intent to keep wrongfully; as, to steal the personal goods of another.

So, technically, the word fits both of these sentences. However, in the context of an immediate struggle for life and limb, one of these synonyms might work better:

1. grab
2. grapple
3. grasp
4. snap up
5. snare

There are other numerous examples, but you get the idea. The question is one of connotation.

Comment: **Grab** sounds right in this context.

Comment: So I would be right to think that the speaker is trying to paint the man in a bad light?

Comment: That would be the indication, @squirrel, unless the speaker simply has a limited vocabulary.